# update_user_meta adding new rows in db for same key

Tags: user-meta

I have added new user meta for a given user. Let's call it `title`. Every time I run

```
$user = get_user_by('login',$username);
update_user_meta($user->ID, 'title','Manager');
```

The meta is not updated. Instead, a new row gets added to the `wp_usermeta` table for this `user` -> `meta_key` -> `meta_value` with a new `umeta_id`.

Also, the meta is not available via `get_user_meta($user->ID);` I feel I'm missing something in order to get this working correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
global $current_user;
$user_id = $current_user->ID; // current user ID
$meta = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'title', 'Manager' ); // subject meta

if($meta != '') // updates meta if exists
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'title', 'Manager');
else // creates new meta if not exists
    add_user_meta($user_id, 'title', 'Manager');
```

Comment: Thx Samuel. I wasn't expecting an answer after so long! :) Your answer works, but the issue wasn't with the wp functions. It was a plugin called W3 Total Cache which some idiot (me) switched on in our dev instance a few months ago. It was caching db queries!

Comment: You're welcome @dewd . Does this mean you your issue is resolved? And yes, I can imagine the pain caused by caching tools, especially when you don't recognize that they are the issue..

Comment: Samuel. Yes, it is, but as I suppose there's no correct answer to resolve the issue, I won't mark any as accepted.